# Getting exit status of somecommand after "if ! somecommand"

Tags: bash

I seem to not be able to get the exit code of the command execution in a Bash if condition:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -eu

if ! curl -sS --fail http://not-there; then
  echo "ERROR: curl failed with exit code of $?" >&2
fi
```

But the `$?` always returns zero, when my `curl` exits with non-zero.

If I don't do the `curl` command inside of the if-condition, then my `$?` returns correctly.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: As an aside, `set -eu` is by no means unambiguously considered a good idea. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) regarding unintended consequences of `set -e`, and [BashFAQ #112](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112) regarding unintended consequences of `set -u`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fair point. I understand `set -eu` often do not catch what one thinks they would, but I also find not having them makes writing Bash much more dangerous for newbies. The net effect is that, I personally prefer them than not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, `$?` is returning the exit status not of `curl`, but of `! curl`.

To preserve the original value, choose a control structure that doesn't require that inversion:

```
curl -sS --fail http://not-there || {
  echo "ERROR: curl failed with exit code of $?" >&2
  exit 1
}
```

...or something akin to:

```
if curl -sS --fail http://not-there; then
  : "Unexpected success"
else
  echo "ERROR: curl failed with exit status of $?" >&2
fi
```

Comment: A gross hack would be to use `until curl -S --fail http://not-there; do echo "Error... $?"; break; done`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve what you want to do is to collect the return code first, then perform the `if` statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu
status=0
curl -sS --fail http://not-there || status=$?
if ((status)) then
  echo "ERROR: curl failed with exit code of $status" >&2
fi
```

I find this method especially convenient when checking for failure of several commands when you want to return an error code at the end of your script or function if any of these has failed.

Please note in the above I use an arithmetic test, which returns true (0) if the value inside is non-zero, and false (non-zero) otherwise.  It is shorter (and more readable to my own taste) than using something like `[[ $status != 0 ]]`.

Comment: Incidentally, your comment on a different answer about attempted iteration over empty arrays causing failures makes a lot more sense when thinking about `set -u` (which I personally avoid in favor of static checking).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  By static checking, to you mean ShellCheck?  Indeed, by obsession with not allowing runtime failures to be silently ignored, I have to specifically handle any case where an error is expected, understood and acceptable.

Comment: Agreed and understood, though I think our conceptions of what constitutes "an error" may differ.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used the word loosely, and it can mean several things.  In my case, I always have an ERR trap active as a part of an "exception" handling mechanism, so I make sure to (1) never "hide" non-zero return codes with constructs such as `if` conditions and logical operators that prevent the trap from being triggered and, as a corollary (2) always use a mechanism other than return codes to indicate failure of functions.  Whenever the ERR trap is triggered, it means I have forgotten a potential failure mode and there is a bug.

Comment: That framework also treats as a bug failure to explicitly handle (or explicitly pass to the calling context) an "exception" before exiting the function where it has been detected.  Here, "exception" has to be understood as an abstraction I have come up with (not related to return codes at all).  Basically, I have created a self-torture device where anything I forget will explode in my face :)