# sh -e: collecting a command's exit status from the "else" branch of an if

Tags: bash, sh

We are writing shell scripts with `set -e` as policy which means that it will exit if any unhandled non-zero exit status appears.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if some_command; then
  experience_happyness
else
  print error status of some_command to log or standard error
  experience_sadness
  exit 1
fi
```

The `$?` expression evaluates to `0` at the beginning of the else branch. If I don't run the `some_command` inside `if` then an eventual error will terminate the shell script immediately.

How can I know the exit status of a program when `set -e` is effective without terminating the script?

I'm interested in `bash` specific solutions too if pure `sh` solutions are not available.

**EDIT**: My bad. as @"that other guy" answered I was mistaken when I told that "$?" evaluates to 0 at the beginning of the else branch. I tried it, but I made some mistake when tried it. Sorry.

I think we may keep this question because of the pro quality answer. Should we?

Comment: `set -e` behavior is [wildly incompatible](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) across different `sh` implementations. That said, *all of them* are required by the POSIX standard to ignore "checked" exit status -- that is, cases where exit status is used for explicit flow control. (See also the exercises below the allegory in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for some examples of where and how the behavior tends to be unhelpful, surprising, and/or unintuitive).

Comment: I wonder if the reason you're seeing this is that your `some_command` has its exit status inverted with `!` -- if so, that would make this question a duplicate of [getting exit status of somecommand after `if ! somecommand`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668312/getting-exit-status-of-somecommand-after-if-somecommand).

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "The $? expression evaluates to 0 at the beginning of the else branch".  $? must be non-zero at the beginning of the commands in the else, or the else wouldn't be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The $? expression evaluates to 0 at the beginning of the else branch.

No it doesn't.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

some_command() { return 42; }

if some_command; then
  echo "Worked"
else
  echo "Command failed with $?"
  exit 1
fi
```

will print `Command failed with 42`.

Comment: This is often due to posting a cleaned up example without checking that the cleaned up version still exhibits the same problem. sh/bash is notorious for breaking on seemingly insignificant changes. The bash tag wiki has more about this.